# Preorder traversal without recursion

Tags: recursion, binary-tree, preorder

I need an algorithm to solve preorder traversal of a binary tree.Please provide me the algo to traverse a tree preorderly without using recursive call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Way to go from recursion to iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration)

Comment: Have you tried anything?  [Googling the problem even?](https://www.google.com/search?q=preorder+tree+traversal+without+recursion)

Comment: You need to use a stack, either system or utility, in order to do the task and it is inherently a recursive process and not constant space. Thus not like the Fibonacci sequence  where you can calculate the value in constant space.